# In Git, how can I make a new commit on a branch with the tree equal to the tree from another commit

Tags: git

I have a situation where I have

```
...--x--y--z   master

...--a--b--c  someOtherBranch
```

I'd like to make a new commit on the master branch that simply changes the file tree to look like the tree of someOtherBranch.  I.e., I want to get to a state

```
...--x--y--z--c1 master

...--a--b--c  someOtherBranch
```

where commit `c1` has a file tree that looks just like that of `c`. (Which presumably means it's exactly the same file tree object.)

How can I do this?

I know this will create a potentially big and undesirable discontinuity between z and c1.

Comment: git merge someOtherBranch on master?

Comment: Or do you mean you *just* want c, in which case cherry pick.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar  The result of the merge depends on the tree associated with z as well as the tree associated with c.  That's not what I want. I want the new commit to have exactly the same tree as c.

Comment: Ok then try cherry-picking as suggested by jonrsharpe

Comment: @jonrsharpe If I understand cherry picking, that would mean that the difference between z and c1 would equal the difference between b and c. That's not what I want. I want the difference between z and c1 to equal the difference between z and c.

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve* here? What *is* someOtherBranch?

Comment: Cherry picking is unlikely to give you the results you want because it doesn't  describe how to turn z into c, it only describes how to turn b into c.  I don't think it's possible to pull the commit over as-is, but you can say make my working tree look like commit c by being on master and saying: `git checkout c .` (the dot is important... that's the part that tells git to make the working tree look like that commit versus checking out c).  From there you can commit, which I think gives you the desired result.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What I am trying to achieve is to have the head of the master branch have a file tree that is equal to the file tree of the current head of someOtherBranch. I could do this by resetting the head of master to be the same as the head of someOtherBranch, but if I did that I'd have trouble pushing master to the origin.  So what I am asking for is a way to make a new commit on the master branch that descends from its current head, z, but whose file tree is that of the head of someOtherBranch.

Comment: That's the X, what's the Y? http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Y is above in the original question.

Comment: No, it isn't. You keep repeating the proposed solution you were unable to implement, but there's no *context*, no information about the actual problem (e.g. what does that branch even represent?) and its constraints (e.g. which parts of the history remain relevant?); that's *not* the Y. It looks like you've got a fix you're happy with, but next time including more background will help people find better solutions that weren't even on your radar.

Comment: According to http://xyproblem.info/, "User asks for help with Y."  So Y is by definition my original question.  In retrospect, now that I understand more, I realize that I could have asked a slightly broader (but more complex) question, i.e. I could have specified a range of acceptable final states rather than focusing on one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not at all clear *why* you want to do this (the usual reasons are covered by `git merge -s ours`, which makes a *merge* commit rather than a single-parent commit), but it's easy to do, <s>using either `git merge --squash -s ours` followed by `git commit`, or</s> using `git commit-tree`.  **Edit**: `-s ours` from master would preserve the wrong tree (`z` instead of `c`).  It *is* possible to use this, but that's if you want a *merge* commit.  See the section below.

(All commands below assume you are on `master` now.)

To use `git commit-tree`, you must provide some extra arguments, which requires more setup:

```
hash=$(git commit-tree -p HEAD -F /tmp/commit-msg someOtherBranch^{tree})
```

for instance, with the commit message stored in the file `/tmp/commit-msg`.  The resulting hash ID is a new commit object that is not yet on any branch but is now easy to "fast-forward-merge" to:

```
git merge --ff-only $hash
```

or to `git reset` to:

```
git reset --hard $hash
```

You can also, as [John Szakmeister commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613968/in-git-how-can-i-make-a-new-commit-with-the-tree-equal-to-the-tree-from-another#comment99802803_56613968), use `git checkout` to overlay another commit's index and work-tree into your current one.  You should `git rm` everything first in case you have a file named `README` and they don't have a `README`, only a `README.md`, for instance.

Or you can use `git read-tree` to do this, which I think is simpler:

```
git read-tree -m -u someOtherBranch; git commit
```

(no need for the `^{tree}` here as `git read-tree` will resolve the commit to a tree all by itself).

#### If you really want a merge after all

The read-tree (or remove-and-checkout) trick can also be used after setting up a true merge, with `git merge -s ours`.  That is:

```
git merge -s ours someOtherBranch
git read-tree -m -u someOtherBranch
git commit
```

will prepare for a merge that would retain `z`, then replace the index and work-tree with that from `c`, then make the new commit `c1` whose tree matches `c` instead of `z`:

```
...--x--y--z--c1   <-- master
             /
...--a--b---c   <-- someOtherBranch
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  In fact, the `git merge -s ours` option is probably what I need.  I don't mind if the new commit has two parents.  That is probably preferable.  But if I am on master, doesn't `git merge -s ours` go the wrong way around? I.e. wouldn't that make the tree the new commit equal the tree of the (former) head of `master` rather than the head of `someotherbranch`?

Comment: Er, yes, `-s ours` means keep the tree of whatever's checked out. If you run this while *on* `master` you'll keep the tree of `z`. You could make the merge with `someOtherBranch` checked out to retain the tree of `c` but then the parent order of the merge commit is backwards (`c` is first parent, `z` is second). I'll edit...

Comment: Last, if you *do* want a two-parent merge, run `git merge -s ours --no-commit` to prepare for it, *then* use the `git rm; git checkout` or `git read-tree -m -u` trick. (Or leave out `-s ours`, ignore any conflicts that occur, and use `git read-tree --reset -u someOtherBranch` to set up the index for the final commit.)

Comment: Thanks again. What I actually did was simpler.  From the `someotherbranch` branch, I did `get merge -s ours master`. That made the new commit c1 with two parents (z, and c in my picture) whose file tree was equal that of commit c in my picture.  Then I did a hard reset of master to the new commit. This ended up with both branches having the same head, c1, but that was fine with me.

Comment: That gives you the parent linkage in the "wrong order". You might not care! It just means that any future historian, going through this repository, using `git log --first-parent` to follow the linkages, will think that `master` was always the `a-b-c-c1` line and that the `x-y-z` line was a failed experiment killed off by merging it into `master` while keeping `master` (the `a-b-c` line).

Comment: That is a good point.   In my case, x-y-z really was a failed experiment (actually the result of a bad merge), so I'm happy to have c as the first parent.